# How do I use the GPU in a AWS Sagemaker ml.t3.2xlarge instance?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pytorch, amazon-sagemaker

I have a notebook ml.t3.2xlarge instance on AWS Sagemaker and I want to train a neural network using pytorch.

The following command returns "False":

```
torch.cuda.is_available()
```

Is there something I need to do to activate the GPU?

When I run the following command:

```
! nvidia-smi
```

then it says "NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.".

I was assuming all the notebook instance types had GPUs, since they're used for training neural networks.

Is it possible to use the GPU in this type of notebook instance and how would I do that?

Comment: You can choose a GPU enabled image type along with GPU enabled instance type and then you don't need to set up the CUDA drivers:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/notebooks-available-images.html https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/notebooks-available-instance-types.html

Answer (score 1):

An `ml.t3.2xlarge` is a CPU instance which has no GPU.
Instead, run your SageMaker notebook instance with one of the GPU instances [listed here](https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-sagemaker-developer-guide/blob/master/doc_source/notebooks-available-instance-types.md), like `ml.g4dn.xlarge`, and make sure to pick the PyTorch kernel for the notebook.